# I'm testing comments on my Flutter App. Application shows yellow bar when comment is too many characters to the right 175 pixels to the right

Tags: android, flutter, dart

title: Row(
children: [
Text(
commentdoc['username'],
style: mystyle(20),
),
SizedBox(
width: 15.0,
),
Text(
commentdoc['comment'],
style:
mystyle(20, Colors.grey, FontWeight.w500),
),
],
),

Comment: Hi @ozkntbk, what exactly is the issue. Your question reads more like a statement.
Please read the guidelines on how to ask a good question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this.

```
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          commentdoc['username'],
                          style: mystyle(20),
                        ),
                        flex: 1,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 15.0,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          commentdoc['comment'],
                          style: mystyle(20, Colors.grey, FontWeight.w500),
                        ),
                        flex: 2,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
```